# What's the right way to run a python script as a daemon (service) in raspbian (or debian)?

Tags: gpio, python, services

I'd like to use my Pi as a home thermostat, with the control loop running in a python script. I want to run it as a daemon on raspbian (debian) at startup.

There's an example bash script in /etc/init.d/skeleton, but it seems unpythonic to mash bash and python together. There are python modules and deb packages that can help with start/stop/alert command processing:

- [daemoncmd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemoncmd/0.1.0) Python
- [daemonize](http://bmc.github.com/daemonize/)
- [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html)
- [launchd](http://launchd.macosforge.org/)
- [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) Debian
- [mattdaemon](https://github.com/plausibility/mattdaemon) Python
- [perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/)
- [runit](http://smarden.sunsite.dk/runit/)
- [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)
- [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) Ubuntu
- [zdaemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zdaemon/2.0.4)

Has anyone had success with a particular approach for daemonizing a "real-time" feedback control loop on the Pi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done this on several projects. https://bitbucket.org/dnetman99/raspberrypiprojects if you look at the gpsdpiTracker, the `trackerServer.py` uses the daemon class to daemonize the script.  I then just use `restartd` to watch if it stops and restarts it, which also means it will start it after boot as well.  I also have used the skeleton file for start, stop daemon, but is not necessary if you use this method.

```
restartd = sudo apt-get install restartd
```

Comment: Thanks! Awesome examples. Will see if I can recycle some of that code. The daemon class is from [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) module based on [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) and restartd is [here](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/restartd).

Comment: Actually looks like you rolled your own Daemon class. Nice.

Comment: Except for the she-bang line, the Demon class in dnetman99's bitbucket is identical to [Sander Marechal's simple daemon](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/) from 2007. Credit where credit is due. Via [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the way we daemonize in the client pybit-client.

https://github.com/nicholasdavidson/pybit

That was designed to run as a daemon on small ARM boxes 24/7.

Handles logging, signal handling, start/stop scripts etc...